# IntStream forEach method in Java 8

Tags: java, lambda

I am trying to learn new concepts introduced in java8.

While I am still learning (and not comfortable with) lambdas.

I got a question.

This is what I understood till now (Hope I am right) -

1. An `interface` with just one abstract method is a `functional interface` e.g. `IntConsumer` that has `accept` method (only abstract method).
2. We write a lambda expression and provides implementation for this method.

Now, While doing a foreach we give a lambda expression -

`(value -> System.out.printf("%d ", value))`

And `foreach` method in `Intstream` takes `IntConsumer` (a `functional interface)` as its type.

So, basically here with this lambda expression we have provided an `implementation` of `accept` method of `IntCosumer`.

Fine till now.

Then, I checked source code for `Intstream` and saw that `foreach` is an abstract method and there is no implementation.

Now, my question is "*How does it know that it has to iterate through the elements"*?

`Lambda` expression only dictated what to do for each element, but who dictates that it has to loop through.

I was expecting something equivalent of this -

```
foreach(IntConsumer cons){
     for(Integer i : this){
       cons.accept();
     }
}
```

Comment: The contract of the `forEach` method dictates the behavior expected of each class that implements the `IntStream` interface (just like any method declared in any interface).

Comment: If you want to find the implementation you will need the **specific** implementation of `IntStream` - e.g. `IntPipeline.Head`. This would be the actual type of the `Object` returned from, for example, `IntStream.of`. The actual logic is **much** more complex than you seem to be expecting - for example, what if I do `IntStream.of(1,2).parallel().forEach()`?

Comment: It's just like any other interface: the implementation is provided by a _class_ that implements the interface.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to *polymorphism*.

Hopefully you have seen this kind of code:

```
interface SomeInterface { ... }
class SomeClass implements SomeInterface { ... }
...
private SomeInterface someMethod() {
    ...
    return new SomeClass();
}
```

`someMethod` is supposed to return `SomeInterface`, yet it returns a `SomeClass`. How is that possible? Because `SomeClass` implements `SomeInterface`.

The same happens in `IntStream`. `IntStream` is an interface. Therefore, what actually happens when you call `stream` on an int array is that it calls a bunch of other methods and finally you reached a method like this in `StreamSupport.class`:

```
public static IntStream intStream(Spliterator.OfInt spliterator, boolean parallel) {
```

In this method, it returns a `new` `IntPipeline.Head`. So the `IntStream` returned by `stream` is actually an `IntPipeline.Head`. Now if we look into the `IntPipeline.Head` class, you will see the implementation  of the for each method:

```
    @Override
    public void forEach(IntConsumer action) {
        if (!isParallel()) {
            adapt(sourceStageSpliterator()).forEachRemaining(action);
        }
        else {
            super.forEach(action);
        }
    }
```

Well, it isn't what it expected, is it? It calls another bunch of methods! Whether or not to look at how they implemented the other methods is your own choice.

Now, the question is, why did they not return `IntPipeline.Head` directly in the `stream` method? This is because returning `IntPipeline.Head` is only the behaviour of the standard JDK. Others can create their own implementation of `IntStream` and make `stream` return their implementation instead. This increases flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

As the javadoc says:

> Performs an action for each element of this stream.

It's an abstract method, so it cannot have implementation. The responsability for implementing (and follow the abstract method's purpose) is of the class which extends `IntStream`.